# Как передать параметры в параметризованный декоратор?

Tags: python, python-3.x, декоратор

День добрый.

Как передаете ЛЮБОЕ кол-во параметров в функцию через параметризованный декоратор?
Вот функция

```
def parametrized_decoder(path_to_log = "files/log.txt"):
  def decorator_logo(fun):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      import pathlib
      import datetime
      log = {}
      fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
      time_start = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt)
      name_fun = fun.__name__
      pesponse = tuple(fun(*args, **kwargs))
       
        ...
      return pesponse

    return wrapper
  return decorator_logo
```

Декорируемая

```
@parametrized_decoder
def yandex_request_put_foldr(path_in_root, folder_of_putting, header):
  ...
  return
```

В данной версии ругается - мол подаете 1 параметр , а требуется 3

```
TypeError: decorator_logo() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Задача - декоратор вешать на любую функцию.
Но где-то есть внешние данные, гдк-то нету.
Как в этом случает параметризовать декоратор...

Comment: _'мол подаете 1 параметр , а требуется 3'_ наоборот, функция принимает 1 параметр, а передано было 3

Comment: если это параметры декоратора, то и передавать их надо декоратору `@decorator_with_arguments(arg1,arg2)`

Answer (score 0):

Вот [хорошая статья](https://python-scripts.com/decorator-arguments)

Вопрос закрыт, ответ найден.